# How to dynamically refer to userforms

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to avoid hardcoding a userform's name into subs that fill out and later retrieve data from said userform. The sub I've included here is the one that is supposed to put the values from the userform into cells on a sheet.

(I'm still pretty new to this)

I've tried several approaches from other solutions to similar problems on stackoverflow to no avail.
The closest I've come to was Screen.ActiveForm but sadly that's for Access, not excel.

I've also tried creating a public object variable but couldn't get that to work either.

The only thing that worked was hardcoding Userform1 into the subs, but that seems like an inefficient way to go about this. I don't see why someone would have to write a new module every time they setup another userform.

```
''''''''''''''''' Userform '''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Ok

' Set CurrentForm = Me.Caption
Interactive_Userforms.EditAdd

End Sub


''''''''''''''''' Module '''''''''''''''''''


Public StartRow, StartColumn, n_TextBoxes As Integer
Public sheet As String
' public CurrentForm as object

Sub EditAdd()

Dim i, j, k  As Integer

i = StartRow
j = StartColumn
k = 1

Do While screen.activeform.Controls("TextBox" & k).Value <> ""

    Worksheets(sheet).Cells(i, j).Value = screen.activeform.Controls("TextBox" & k).Value

    Debug.Print (Worksheets(sheet).Cells(i + StartRow, j + StartColumn).Value)

    i = i + 1
    k = k + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

What I would expect to be able to do is to eventually have any userform be able to call this sub to retrieve the values on its textbox controls and nicely put them into a worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want EditAdd Sub to be called by userforms, you can change your EditAdd 
 signature to `Sub EditAdd(Form as Object)` or `Sub EditAdd(Form as Userform)` then you can pass userform instance itself as "Me" when you call EditAdd

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Ok

' Set CurrentForm = Me.Caption
Interactive_Userforms.EditAdd(Me)

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh good! I'm not the only person that thought this! Your answer beat mine by 42 seconds (nooooo... !!! ). I'm happy to give you your first *upvote* though 

Comment: Thanks @PGSystemTester so much!, I'll upvote as well as a "Thanks"

Comment: Hey Bilal and @PGSystemTester, thanks for the quick response!
I tried your suggestion and now my command button that calls the form doesn't work for some reason. 
   " .show"
is no longer allowed on the form?
The error says it's a type mismatch.

Comment: did you type in brackets around "Me"? i.e. Interactive_Userforms.EditAdd(Me) If so please remove the brackets, it should be .....  EditAdd Me

Comment: That did it, works like a charm. 
I might just finish my first project thanks to you guys :P. I give thee a thousands thanks

Comment: Happy to help, could you please make the answer accepeted, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this answer is too simple given your code, but it seems like you should be able to just include a parameter for the macro to capture the Form calling it.

Something like...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Ok

Call Interactive_Userforms, Me

End Sub
```

and then your public module would have...

```
Sub EditAdd(myUserForm As UserForm)
'... etc....
        Worksheets(Sheet).Cells(i, j).Value = myUserForm("TextBox" & k).Value
'... etc.

End Sub
```